# minicart.js not working, cart is not popping up

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am using [Minicart.JS](http://minicartjs.com/) for my simple paypal shopping cart. But this is not working as it should. The cart is not popping up if I click 'add to cart' button.

Here's my code.

```
<html>
<body>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/minicart/3.0.3/minicart.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            paypal.minicart.render();
        </script>


        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="labs-feedback-minicart@paypal.com" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Product" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00" />
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="1.50">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="2.50">
                <strong>Test Product</strong>

                <p>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" value="" /> I agree to the terms</label>
                </p>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" />
            </form>

    <script>
        paypal.minicart.render();

        paypal.minicart.cart.on('checkout', function (evt) {
            var hasAgreed = !!document.getElementById('terms').checked;

            if (!hasAgreed) {
                alert('You must agree to the terms!');
        evt.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the actual site.](http://www.goscrub.com/test-page/) , I found an error in console that said:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null
```

I am not sure how to fix this, please let me know what's wrong with my setup. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - the code you have listed is successfully supporting launch of the Paypal pop-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Add to cart button to not be saved on PayPal (In Profit and loss Section) and also unprotect code after the button is created right before you copy and paste it :)

Hope this helps :)